# Can't find variable DeviceEventEmitter

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I am implementing the `react-native-push-notification` package in react-native.

In the example on the link: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#2-specify-handlers-for-the-notification-actions.

Error is displayed: Can't find variable: DeviceEventEmitter.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the DeviceEventEmitter from 'react-native'

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';
```